# How to handle RejectedAccessException when calling a step from a common shared library in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to create a common shared library for the common steps used in my Jenkins scripts in multiple projects.
I have a step sendBuildInfoSlack which earlier called a function defined in the same JenkinsFile. I moved it to its own step in a common shared library under vars folder.

[image]

The call function of this file is calling the same function that used to work directly in JenkinsFile. However, it is giving me this error:

```
Scripts not permitted to use method groovy.lang.GroovyObject invokeMethod java.lang.String java.lang.Object (org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2 sendBuildInfoSlack java.util.LinkedHashMap). Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature.
Error when executing failure post condition:
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use method groovy.lang.GroovyObject invokeMethod java.lang.String java.lang.Object (org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2 sendBuildInfoSlack java.util.LinkedHashMap)
```

I did not expect to run into this error, especially since while declaring Global Pipeline Libraries it explicitly says that **These libraries will be trusted, meaning they run without sandbox restrictions**

Also, it is not clear to me which method is causing this issue.

I would prefer if I did not have to whitelist every function since I expect this library to grow to cover more widely used functions and I do not have permission to whitelist either.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, sorry for not seeing it back in 2020 but we were all dealing with stuff.

Jenkins has a long-standing "quirk" that arises from an interaction of how groovy does method resolution and the way the sandbox security manager is set up. This quirk means that if you typo a method name or pass in the wrong parameters (e.g. if you're jumping back and forth between Jenkins and python and try to pass in a param as `isFoo=true` when you should have used `isFoo: true`, or if you [forget a block after the function when the function requires it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77887959/107331)) you get a `RejectedAccessException` that refers to `GroovyObject invokeMethod` instead of a sensible error like `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException`. It's been this way since at least 2016, so I wouldn't hold your breath on it getting addressed any time soon.

So what this error is *really* telling you is "I couldn't find the method called `sendBuildInfoSlack` that takes a `Map` as its only parameter".

One possibility is that you've declared your method incorrectly ([as in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64163887/107331)) and created a `sendBuildInfoSlack` that doesn't take named parameters with the common `funcName paramName: value` syntax. However, since it used to work when it was all in the same file, that's unlikely. (though you did change the top-level definition to `def call` from `def sendBuildInfoSlack`, correct?)

More likely is that for some reason your Jenkinsfile isn't loading the library file, and so can't see `sendBuildInfoSlack` at all. Do you have an `@Library` declaration at the top of your Jenkinsfile? Are you able to call other functions in that same directory?