# Global Shared Library Custom step RejectedAccessException

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to DRY out one of our jenkins pipelines and move some logic to a shared library. I have the library set as a global shared library but I am still getting security errors which I don't understand. As far as I understand I global shared libraries should not have this issue.

I have set up the shared library following the documentation. I have a seprate repository. Since I am just trying to wrap repeated steps into a single custom step my repo looks like this:
[image: shared library layout]

In `vars` I have a single groovy file which contains the following:

```
// vars/buildResolverMicroService.groovy

def call(String configFile, String artifactName, String versionString, String classifier) {

    rtMavenRun (
        tool: 'Maven', // Tool name from Jenkins configuration
        pom: 'pom.xml',
        goals: "clean package -P prod -Dloadme.file=${configFile}",
        resolverId: "MAVEN_RESOLVER"
    )

    fileOperations([
        /** Some file operations **/
    ])

    zip(zipFile: "${artifactName}-${versionString}-${classifier}.zip", archive: true, dir: 'build/')
}
```

Then in my Jenkinsfile I do this:

```
@Library("my-library@master") _

branch = env.BRANCH_NAME
version = '1.0.0'

versionString = branch == 'master' ? version : "${version}-SNAPSHOT"
artifactName = 'my-artifact'
pomFileName = "${artifactName}-${versionString}.pom"

repo = branch == 'master' ? 'Releases' : 'Snapshots'
repositoryLocation = "my/${repo}/in/artifactory"

currentBuild.displayName = branch == 'master' ? versionString : "${versionString}.${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"

artifactoryServerId = 'artifactory-repo1'

pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'my-agent'
    }

    stages {

        stage ('Setup') {
            steps {

                rtServer (
                    id: 'Artifactory'
                )

                rtMavenResolver (
                    id: 'MAVEN_RESOLVER',
                    serverId: 'Artifactory'
                )

                /** more setup **/
            }
        }

        stage ('Build Service 1') {
            steps {
                buildResolverMicroService configFile: 'config1.txt', classifier: 'service1'
            }
        }

        stage ('Build Service 2') {
            steps {
                buildResolverMicroService configFile: 'config2.txt', classifier: 'service2'
            }
        }

        /** Upload to artifactory **/
    }
    post {
        always {
            cleanWs()
        }
    }
}
```

The build will complete the `Setup` stage successfully but will fail with the following exception from my custom step:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use method groovy.lang.GroovyObject invokeMethod java.lang.String java.lang.Object (org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2 buildResolverMicroService java.util.LinkedHashMap)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.whitelists.StaticWhitelist.rejectMethod(StaticWhitelist.java:270)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:159)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:161)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:165)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:135)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:100)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.delegateAndExecute(ModelInterpreter.groovy:137)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.executeSingleStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:661)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.catchRequiredContextForNode(ModelInterpreter.groovy:395)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.catchRequiredContextForNode(ModelInterpreter.groovy:393)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.executeSingleStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:660)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:288)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.toolsBlock(ModelInterpreter.groovy:544)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.toolsBlock(ModelInterpreter.groovy:543)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:276)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.withEnvBlock(ModelInterpreter.groovy:443)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.withEnvBlock(ModelInterpreter.groovy:442)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:275)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.withCredentialsBlock(ModelInterpreter.groovy:481)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.withCredentialsBlock(ModelInterpreter.groovy:480)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:274)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.inDeclarativeAgent(ModelInterpreter.groovy:586)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.inDeclarativeAgent(ModelInterpreter.groovy:585)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:272)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.stageInput(ModelInterpreter.groovy:356)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.stageInput(ModelInterpreter.groovy:355)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:261)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.inWrappers(ModelInterpreter.groovy:613)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.inWrappers(ModelInterpreter.groovy:612)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:259)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.withEnvBlock(ModelInterpreter.groovy:443)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.withEnvBlock(ModelInterpreter.groovy:442)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:254)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:86)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor251.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CollectionLiteralBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatch(CollectionLiteralBlock.java:55)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CollectionLiteralBlock$ContinuationImpl.item(CollectionLiteralBlock.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor495.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:185)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:400)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:96)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:312)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:276)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Does anybody have any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but maybe an answer will still be useful to someone.

The issue is that you declared your function like like this:

```
def call(String configFile, String artifactName, String versionString, String classifier) {
```

and you called it like this:

```
buildResolverMicroService configFile: 'config1.txt', classifier: 'service1'
```

If you had called your function with exactly four string values (the way you declared it), it would have worked:

```
buildResolverMicroService 'config1.txt', 'myArtifactName', 'myVersionString', 'service1'
```

Instead though you called your function using groovy's named arguments syntax, which ends up trying to bundle all the named arguments into a map and shoving that at your function.

You should have gotten a "no such method" error or similar, but in Jenkins there's a quirk that's been there since at least 2016 that the security system and the standard groovy method resolution order get in a fight and typoing a method name or calling it with the wrong argument types yields a `RejectedAccessException` referring to `groovy.lang.GroovyObject invokeMethod`.

What you wanted to do was define your function something like this:

```
// vars/buildResolverMicroService.groovy

def call(Map params = [:]) {
    String configFile = params.containsKey('configFile') ? params.configFile : "defaultConfigFile.txt"
    String artifactName = params.containsKey('artifactName') ? params.artifactName : "defaultArtifactName"
    String versionString = params.containsKey('versionString') ? params.versionString : "1.0"
    String classifier = params.containsKey('classifier') ? params.classifier : "default"

    rtMavenRun (
        tool: 'Maven', // Tool name from Jenkins configuration
        pom: 'pom.xml',
        goals: "clean package -P prod -Dloadme.file=${configFile}",
        resolverId: "MAVEN_RESOLVER"
    )

    fileOperations([
        /** Some file operations **/
    ])

    zip(zipFile: "${artifactName}-${versionString}-${classifier}.zip", archive: true, dir: 'build/')
}
```

Then invoke as before. (e.g. `buildResolverMicroService configFile: 'config2.txt', classifier: 'service2'`)